# How to encode a call to deploy a proxy inside a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, constructor, upgrading

In `hardhat`, I am deploying an upgradeable smart contract using this script:

```
const v1contract = await upgrades.deployProxy(
      V1contract, 
      [
         "0xF8e6A72C0e72E0Eb510bD20097b0522Eae4B24E4", // _defaultAdmin
         "Smart NFT", // _name
         "SNFT", // _symbol
         "My Smart Wallet", // _contractURI
         [], // _trustedForwarders
         "0xF8e6A72C0e72E0Eb510bD20097b0522Eae4B24E4", // _royaltyRecipient
         0 // _royaltyBps */
      ], {
         gasPrice: gas, 
         initializer: "initialize",
         kind: "uups",
         constructorArgs: ["0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889"]
   });
```

As you can see, it takes 1 constructor argument in addition to the `initialize` function.

How can I reproduce this behaviour inside a smart contract? This is the code I have and I don't know where to add the constructor argument:

```
   function createSmartWallet(
        uint256 _smartWalletId,
        address _defaultAdmin,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _contractURI,
        address[] memory _trustedForwarders,
        address _royaltyRecipient,
        uint256 _royaltyBps
    ) public {
        SmartWalletProxy smartWallet = new SmartWalletProxy(address(proxy), address(this), abi.encodeCall(SmartWallet(payable(address(0))).initialize, (_defaultAdmin, _name, _symbol, _contractURI, _trustedForwarders, _royaltyRecipient, _royaltyBps)));
        smartWallets[_smartWalletId] = address(smartWallet);
    }
```

Comment: upgradeable contracts must not have constructors, they only have initialize functions .

Comment: Can you please take a look at this smart contract? I am using it has a base and it has a constructor and an initializer: https://github.com/thirdweb-dev/contracts/blob/main/contracts/multiwrap/Multiwrap.sol

Comment: you want to deploy an upgradeable contract with createSmartWallet() function ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. And the upgradeable smart contract I want to deploy is the one I just shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code I ended up using and it works:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/CountersUpgradeable.sol";
import "../proxy/SmartVaultProxy.sol";
import "../vault/SmartVault.sol";

contract SmartVaultFactory is Initializable, OwnableUpgradeable {
    using CountersUpgradeable for CountersUpgradeable.Counter;
    mapping(uint256 => address) private smartVaults;
    mapping(address => address[]) private smartVaultsPerUser;
    CountersUpgradeable.Counter private counter;
    string private version;
    address implementation;
    address private feeAddress;
    uint256 private fullyAllocatedFee;
    uint256 private coAllocatedFee;

    function initialize(address _smartVault, address _feeAddress, uint256 _fullyAllocatedFee, uint256 _coAllocatedFee, string memory _version) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init();
        version = _version;
        fullyAllocatedFee = _fullyAllocatedFee;
        coAllocatedFee = _coAllocatedFee;
        implementation = _smartVault;
        feeAddress = _feeAddress;
    }

    function versionContract() public view returns (string memory) {
        return version;
    }

    function createSmartVault(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        bool _coAllocated
    ) public payable collectFee(_coAllocated) {
        SmartVaultProxy newSmartVault = new SmartVaultProxy(address(implementation), abi.encodeWithSelector(SmartVault(payable(address(0))).initialize.selector, msg.sender, _name, _symbol, _coAllocated));
        uint256 currentCounter = counter.current();
        smartVaults[currentCounter] = address(newSmartVault);
        counter.increment();
        smartVaultsPerUser[msg.sender].push(address(newSmartVault));
    }
}
```